# Magento 2 : Rest Api for search customer by name

Tags: magento2, rest-api, search

I want to search customer by name. Any options to search customer by name using Rest API in Magento 2

Comment: yes  issue resolved

Comment: Gagan, if answer helps you then you mark accepted to those answer, so it will help future readers, you can mark accept answer by clicking (✓) next to answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GET    /V1/customers/search` with searchcriteria.

Something like the following:

```
http://my.website.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/search? 
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=firstname& 
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=%& 
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like
```

Comment: It get all customer name, how to get customer according name please explain according explain

Answer (score 1):

In order to search customer by name using REST API. I use the firstname for search, you can use lastname as well.

```
<?php
 //**** Use your Url ********************//
 $magentoURL = "http://127.0.0.1/mage2/"; 

 $apiURL = $magentoURL."index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token";
 $data = array("username" => "APIUSER", "password" => "APIUSERWD");
 $data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($apiURL);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","Content-Length: ".strlen($data_string)));
 $token = curl_exec($ch);

//decoding generated token and saving it in a variable
 $token= json_decode($token);

//******************************************//

//Using above token into header
 $headers = array("Authorization: Bearer ".$token);

// **** Your search customer name **********//
 $customername = "abc";    

//API URL to get all Magento 2 modules
$requestUrl = $magentoURL.'index.php/rest/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=firstname&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%25'.$customername.'%25&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like';

$ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);

//decoding result
 $result= json_decode($result);

//printing result
 echo "<pre>";print_r($result);

?>
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: @Gagan If it's work then please mark my answer correct so it's helps others as well. keep coding :) thanks :)

Comment: can we search by email?